# FastAPI - return Single element in from Database

Tags: list, get, fastapi

I have 2 api endpoints. This one returns a list of all my users.

```
@app.get("/entity/", response_model=List[schemas.Userentity])
def read_entities(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    users = crud.get_entities(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return users

def get_entities(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Userentity).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

This works fine. See the data:

```
[
{
"id": "89f8a844-a30e-41b2-947d-6eb0fcadb1bf",
"email": "xxx@hotmail.com",
"first_name": "xxx",
"last_name": "xxx",
"username": "schoedeld",
"created_timestamp": "1633711745164"
},
{
"id": "abd6bb6b-ad80-431c-9f64-d9e651638f4c",
"email": "xxxsd@hotmail.com",
"first_name": "xxx",
"last_name": "xxx",
"username": "xxx",
"created_timestamp": "1633711733338"
},
{
"id": "ad0bd5ca-5aed-4d7f-a6ac-2620f2133685",
"email": "xxxx@hotmail.com",
"first_name": "fsdfs",
"last_name": "fsdfs",
"username": "testadmin",
"created_timestamp": "1633710812666"
}
]
```

Here I have an endpoint to return a single user:

I could return a List with a single element, but I would like to return a single value, so I updated my endpoint to this:

```
@app.get("/entity/{id}", response_model=schemas.Userentity)
def read_entity(id: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = crud.get_entity(db, id=id)
    return user

def get_entity(db: Session, id: str):
    return db.query(models.Userentity).filter_by(id=id)
```

This results in the following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 6 validation errors for Userentity
response -> id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> email
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> first_name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> last_name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> username
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> created_timestamp
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I am pretty new to FastAPI and do not understand why this error happens, can anyone help me and explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually running your SQLAlchemy query, so you're returning the query itself:

```
return db.query(models.Userentity).filter_by(id=id)
```

Instead you should make SQLAlchemy run your query by either:

```
# raise an exception if not exactly one row is returned (so more than one or zero)
return db.query(models.Userentity).filter_by(id=id).one()

# Either one or zero rows - return `None` if user wasn't found
return db.query(models.Userentity).filter_by(id=id).one_or_none()

# Return None if user isn't found, otherwise return the first row
# (multiple rows isn't an error)
return db.query(models.Userentity).filter_by(id=id).first()
```

Next time attach set debugger breakpoint at the `return` call from your view function (or at least `print` the value), and you can see exactly what you're trying to return to FastAPI for serialization.